# Error at compiling, not a typo as far as I see

Tags: c++

```
class Triangulo: public Figura
{
    public:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    void dibujar_triangulo()
    {
        cout<<"Se ha dibujado un triangulo color "<<color<<" con coordenadas "<<
        "("<<x1<<","<<y1<<")"<<endl<<"("<<x2<<","<<y2<<")"<<endl<<"("<<x3<<","<<y3<")"<<endl;
    }
};
```

I've got this error:

```
invalid operands of types 'const char [2]' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'
```

What's wrong?

Also, Here's the whole code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Figura
{
    public:
    string color, nombre;
    int num_lados;
    void establecer_color(string param)
    {
        color=param;
    }
    string obtener_color()
    {
        string a;
        cin>>a;
        return a;
    }
    void establecer_lados(int param)
    {
        num_lados=param;
    }
    int obtener_lados()
    {
        int a;
        cin>>a;
        return a;
    }
};

class Circulo: public Figura
{
    public:
    int x, y;
    void dibujar_circulo()
    {
        cout<<"Se ha dibujado un circulo color "<<color<<" con centro en ("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<endl;
    }
};

class Rectangulo: public Figura
{
    public:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    void dibujar_rectangulo()
    {
        cout<<"Se ha dibujado un rectangulo color "<<color<<" con coordenadas "
        <<"("<<x1<<","<<y1<<")"<<endl<<"("<<x2<<","<<y2<<")"<<endl;
    }
};

class Triangulo: public Figura
{
    public:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    void dibujar_triangulo()
    {
        cout<<"Se ha dibujado un triangulo color "<<color<<" con coordenadas "<<
        "("<<x1<<","<<y1<<")"<<endl<<"("<<x2<<","<<y2<<")"<<endl<<"("<<x3<<","<<y3<")"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Circulo Cir;
    Triangulo Tri;
    Rectangulo Rec;
    int i;
    initsw:
    cout<<"Eliga:"<<endl<<"1.\tCirculo"<<endl<<"2.\tRectangulo"
    <<endl<<"3.\tTriangulo"<<endl<<"4.\tSalir"<<endl;
    cin>>i;
    cout<<"Indique el color de su figura"<<endl;
    cin>>Cir.color;
    Tri.color=Cir.color;
    Rec.color=Cir.color;
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
        cout<<"Por favor introduzca el centro de su circulo:(x,y)"<<endl;
        scanf("(%d,%d)",&(Cir.x),&(Cir.y));
        Cir.dibujar_circulo();
        break;
        case 2:
        cout<<"Por favor introduzca las coordenadas de su rectangulo:(x1,y1),(x2,y2)"<<endl;
        scanf("(%d,%d),(%d,%d)",&(Rec.x1),&(Rec.y1),&(Rec.x2),&(Rec.y2));
        Rec.dibujar_rectangulo();
        break;
        case 3:
        cout<<"Por favor introduzca las coordenadas de su triangulo:(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)"<<endl;
        scanf("(%d,%d),(%d,%d),(%d,%d)",&(Tri.x1),&(Tri.y1),&(Tri.x2),&(Tri.y2),&(Tri.x3),&(Tri.y3));
        Tri.dibujar_triangulo();
        break;
        case 4:
        goto end;
        break;
        default:
        cout<<"Error, elija otra opcion"<<endl;
        goto initsw;
    }
    end:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make it easier for us and tell us which line the error is on?

Comment: It was on the first block of code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a typo. You only wrote `<` before the last `")"` in your function. Some things are just easier to spot with properly formatted code:

```
void dibujar_triangulo()
{
    cout << "Se ha dibujado un triangulo color " << color << " con coordenadas "
         << "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ")" << endl
         << "(" << x2 << "," << y2 << ") "<< endl
         << "(" << x3 << "," << y3 < ")" << endl;
//                                 ^^ should be <<
}
```

Comment: @Juan I copied and pasted your code verbatim and fixed the original error, and it compiled successfully.  It might be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Juan: What is the error? Runtime? Compile time? If it's too big of code, make a new question. :)

Comment: @Juan: the code compiles cleanly with the '<' replaced by '<<'.  So, where is your problem with `scanf()` coming from - and why are you using `scanf()` in C++, anyway?

Comment: @Jonathan: The old format functions have their place in C++, since formatting with streams can be bothersome and not as clean as using those function. Also, talking about the number of functions called... though the optimizer should be able to eliminate most of it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one '<' from your large collection of '<<' operators:

```
void dibujar_triangulo()
{
    cout << "Se ha dibujado un triangulo color " << color << " con coordenadas " <<
    "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ")" << endl <<
    "(" << x2 << "," << y2 << ")" << endl <<
    "(" << x3 << "," << y3<")" << endl;
}
```

Should be:

```
    "(" << x3 << "," << y3 << ")" << endl;
```

The moral of the story is to lay out your code so that the regularities (and irregularities) can be seen easily.  Squeezing everything onto one line makes it hard to read - and therefore to spot the errors.  Using spaces around binary operators helps.

Noting the over-use of `endl` that [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob) pointed out, I'd consider writing:

```
void dibujar_triangulo()
{
    cout << "Se ha dibujado un triangulo color " << color << " con coordenadas " <<
        "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ")\n" <<
        "(" << x2 << "," << y2 << ")\n" <<
        "(" << x3 << "," << y3 << ")"   << endl;
}
```

Or maybe even keep the coordinates all on a single line:

```
void dibujar_triangulo()
{
    cout << "Se ha dibujado un triangulo color " << color << " con coordenadas\n" <<
        "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << "), " <<
        "(" << x2 << "," << y2 << "), " <<
        "(" << x3 << "," << y3 << ")"   << endl;
}
```

A couple more points:

- You don't need either `#include <stdio.h>` or `#include <conio.h>` to get the original code to compile (or, at least, I don't on MacOS X 10.6.7 with GCC/G++ 4.6.0).  I simply commented out those lines.
- You mention having problems with `scanf()`.  You should not usually use `<stdio.h>` in general or the `scanf()` family of functions in particular when you code in C++.

Comment: The last point is bad info. It's perfectly fine to use the format functions in C++, see my comment on my answer.

Comment: @Xeo: your opinion is duly noted; my opinion is as yet unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
<<y3<")"<<endl;
```

should have been

```
<<y3<<")"<<endl;
```

As an aside, one of my rules is: never say `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. `std::endl` does more than just end a line. It also flushes the buffered output data to the OS, which can mean an expensive system call *every time it is invoked*.

Try this:

```
cout<<"Se ha dibujado un triangulo color "
      <<color<<" con coordenadas "
      << "("
      <<x1<<","<<y1
      <<")\n("
      <<x2<<","<<y2
      <<")\n("
      <<x3<<","<<y3
      <<")\n";
```

Comment: +1: Good point about the over-abundant use of `endl`; nevertheless, I find that layout uncomfortable to read - see my answer for a preferable layout (though I have not fixed the `endl` problem you so accurately diagnose).

Comment: @Jonathan, agreed, your layout is more readable, and more likely to draw attention to this error. It's easy to fix your use of `endl` and stay in your style -- `<< ")\n" <<`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you only have one `<` after `y3` on this line:

```
"("<<x1<<","<<y1<<")"<<endl<<"("<<x2<<","<<y2<<")"<<endl<<"("<<x3<<","<<y3<")"<<endl;
                                                     //The error is here. ^
```

Like others have said, it helps to format your code well.  A more readable form of your code snippet might look like this:

```
class Triangulo: public Figura
{
    public:

    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;

    void dibujar_triangulo()
    {
        cout << "Se ha dibujado un triangulo color " << color<< " con coordenadas "
             << "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ")" << endl
             << "(" << x2 << "," << y2 << ")" << endl
             << "(" << x3 << "," << y3 << ")" << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo:

```
... <<y3<")"<<endl;
//      ^ error here, < instead of <<
```